# Question about the Dirac Field: determining the scalars inside the integral on the spinors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, dirac-equation, spinors

**You can read only this first paragraph to understand my problem. In the second one I explain how I tried to understand but it is not successful**.

In my QFT course we wrote :

$$ \psi(x)= 2m \int d\widetilde{q} (b_{\alpha}(\vec{q})u^{\alpha}(\vec{q}) e^{-i q x} + d_\alpha^{*}(\vec{q})v^{\alpha}(\vec{q})e^{+i q x}) $$

Where $\psi$ is the Dirac field associated to the Dirac equation.

$b_{\alpha}$ and $q_{\alpha}$ are scalars, $u^{\alpha}$ and $v^{\alpha}$ are spinors.

We wrote the property :

$$b_{\lambda}(\vec{p})=\int d^3x e^{+ipx} \bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{p}) \gamma^0 \psi(x) $$

But I don't see how we could integrate on $d^3x$ **the result should depends on $x^0$ then**.

I first thought it was a mistake and we had to integrate on $d^4x$ but then I found it probably doesn't depend on the value of $x^0$ even without integration on it, but I would like to check this because it is a little surprising.

---

---

First : the two important properties to keep in mind are :

$$ \bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{p}) \gamma^0 u^\alpha(\vec{p})=\frac{p^0}{m}\delta^{\lambda, \alpha}$$
$$ \bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{-p}) \gamma^0 v^\alpha(\vec{p})=0$$

Now I do the calculation with $d^3x$ :

$$\int d^3x e^{+ipx} \bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{p}) \gamma^0 \psi(x)=\\
2m\int d^3x d\widetilde{q} e^{i(p-q)x}b_{\alpha}(\vec{q})\bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{p}) \gamma^0 u^{\alpha}(\vec{q})+2m\int d^4x d\widetilde{q} e^{i(p+q)x}d_{\alpha}^{*}(\vec{q})\bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{p}) \gamma^0 v^{\alpha}(\vec{q})$$

I have :

$$ \int d^3x e^{i(p-q)x}=e^{i(p_0-q_0)x_0}(2 \pi)^3 \delta^3(\vec{q}-\vec{p})$$

And **as $\vec{p}=\vec{q}$, then $p_0(\vec{p})=q_0(\vec{q})$ then the result doesn't depend on $x_0$ finally**

=> I found this surprising (in fact it is the first time I encounter this), so I just want to check if I am right or if there is something I misunderstood.

And when I finish the calculation I end up with :

$$\int d^3x e^{+ipx} \bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{p}) \gamma^0 \psi(x)=\\
2m\int d\widetilde{q} (2\pi)^3 \delta(\vec{p}-\vec{q})b_{\alpha}(\vec{p})\bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{p}) \gamma^0 u^{\alpha}(\vec{p})+2m\int d\widetilde{q} (2 \pi)^3 \delta(\vec{p}+\vec{q})d_{\alpha}^{*}(\vec{-p})\bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{p}) \gamma^0 v^{\alpha}(\vec{-p})$$

And by using the two properties I wrote in the beginning of this paragraph, I end up with :

$$\int d^3x e^{+ipx} \bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{p}) \gamma^0 \psi(x)=\\
2m\int \frac{d^3q}{(2 \pi)^3 2 q^0} (2\pi)^3 \delta(\vec{p}-\vec{q})b_{\alpha}(\vec{p})\frac{q^0}{m}=b_\alpha(\vec{p})$$

Am I right? In fact we integrate on $d^3x$ and the results doesn't depend on $x^0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If
$$
b_{\lambda}(\vec{p})=\int d^3x e^{+ipx} \bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{p}) \gamma^0 \psi(x)
$$
then (you'll have to prove this):
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}b_{\lambda}(\vec{p})=\int d^3x e^{+ipx} \bar{u^{\lambda}}(\vec{p}) \gamma^0 (i\!\!\not\!\partial+m)\psi(x)
$$
possibly up to a phase.

From this we conclude that, even if we do **not** integrate over $\mathrm dt$, the result is independent of $t$ (why?).

Comment: (If you try and fail to prove this, I can refer you to a book where the calculation is done in detail)

Comment: Ok, thus there is no mistake in my course. But do you think my proof is wrong (if you have time to check it of course) ? Thank you !!

Comment: @StarBucK yes, your proof seems to be fine (except perhaps for some numeric factors such as phases; I havent looked at your proof in detail, step by step). In fact, your proof is pretty standard, and you can find it in most QFT books (in the Dirac equation section).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. It is probably obvious but as QFT is new for me I need to check some calculations to be sure that I understand.

Comment: @StarBucK excuse my wording: I didnt intend to suggest that it was obvious. It is not. I just meant to say that, if you need more details, you can check a book on the subject and you'll find them. Cheers! :-)

Comment: I didn't understood things in that way dont worry !! Thanks